# JQuery toolbar with draggable elements, followed by popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, widget, toolbar

I would like to develop a fancy function for adding widgets to my webpage.
The plan is to add a toolbar with icons to the top of the page. For example, one of these icons could represent a graph. It would be nice if the elements in the toolbar can be dragged and dropped on a specific position on the web page.
After releasing the mouse button a popup form should open, where the details of the element can be set. After pressing finished/save, the element should be pinned on the position where the mouse was released.

That was my mind speaking, but now realism kicks in... How can I achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution for this would be to use jquery + jquery-ui.

```
$('.move').draggable().mouseup(function(e) { 
var $t = $(this);        
var p = $('<div></div>');
p.addClass('pop');
p.css('top', e.pageY).css('left',e.pageX);
$('body').append(p);
$t.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave mousedown mouseup');
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DVHuY/1/

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not expect it to be that simple. One additional question: You used a alert, would it be possible to add a div (or another html element) to the selected position as well?

Comment: Yes, of course. The alert is just to 'mark the spot' where you place whatever functionality you need.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle link in my answer to show you how to create the new div on mouse position once you trigger mouseup.

Comment: Awesome, really nice:) Thank you very much for your help, this looks like a nice solution for my question:)